# Hitting multiple levels of a building with a flamethrower

Tags: savage-worlds

If I use a cone-attack that is partially obstructed by a building, how would that influence the area of effect? For instance, if we were fighting in a ruined building and I shot through a hole in a wall, would I still hit what is behind that wall? And if someone is on the floor above me, would I still be able to hit that person? What if there are holes in the floor/ceiling (depending on where you stand) as well? Would part of my cone-attack be able to travel through those and hit something?

Adding pictures of the trajectory of the attack and what I'd be able to hit depending on what kind of obstructions I face would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area affect attacks, which includes flamethrowers, affect all things under their template. Walls and such provide cover though: the quality of cover gives the target a number of armor points (SWD, “Area Effect Attacks — Cover”, p. 70) against the flamethrower's effect equal to the range modifier the cover is normally worth (as on page 67).

So it would depend on the exact situation, and where the walls are compared to the flamethrower.

> if we were fighting in a ruined building and I shot through a hole in a wall, would I still hit what is behind that wall?

If you're shooting the flame through an opening in the wall, the walls aren't in the way of the template at all and don't provide cover at all. Vulnerable targets inside the room on the other side will take the full force of the attack.

> if someone is on the floor above me, would I still be able to hit that person?

Not if there are no openings for the flame to reach them. The cover modifiers only go up to “Near Total Cover” — anything else and they're not eligible targets at all, and the template won't go through the wall. If the template is completely blocked, it won't magically go through solid walls or floors; it needs some way to flow around the cover.

Which brings us to…

> What if there are holes in the floor/ceiling (depending on where you stand) as well? Would part of my cone-attack be able to travel through those and hit something?

Yes, absolutely. If they're small holes, then the floor between the flamethrower and the targets would count as Near Total Cover and give them a +6 AR against the attack. If it's a ruined building with large gaps, enough to see parts of the people on the floor above, then the degree of cover and the AR bonus it gives will be less.

As usual with Cover, your GM will determine as necessary what degree of cover each target enjoys. Generally though, if you can't see the target at all from where you're firing, even if there are openings, it will count as Near Total Cover since no fraction of the target is visible (which is how the lesser degrees of cover are measured).

---

As is traditional, [a Clint Black post](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=327244#327244) confirming that flamethrowers affect all targets under the template, unless they're fully closed off from the flames, and otherwise cover counts as bonus AR:

> Area Effect attacks affect everything in the area equally, so unless the target has full coverage sealed armor, they won't get any benefit against an AE attack of any nature.
>
> […]
>
> Yep. The above answer only relates to worn Armor. Cover still acts as armor against area effect attacks, including flamethrowers.